# How can I find the java.net.URL for an image needed for ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, icons, imageicon

I'm trying to add an ImageIcon to a JLabel I'm adding to a JPanel to get Graphics for my Java Swing game. However, I can't seem to even create the ImageIcon for the JLabel with my current code. I've already tried looking through Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find an answer that fit my issue. pls help

```
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(Class c, String file) {
        File f = new File(file);
        String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        
        java.net.URL imgURL = c.getResource(path);
        
        System.out.println(imgURL);
        System.out.println(path);
        
        if (path != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(path);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Called from:

```
Graphic startScreenG = new Graphic();
        Icon startScreenI = startScreenG.createImageIcon(MyAppClass, "download.jpg");
        JLabel startScreen = new JLabel(startScreenI);
        Screen.add(startScreen);
```

This returns:

> null
>
> C:\Users*justmyname*\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IA\download.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Note that `getResource` works by name not file path. So for the `c.getResource(path)` to work as you intent, "download.jpg" file would need to be in the classpath IIRC. But since you already have a File object that represents the image file that you need, you could simply call `f.toURI().toURL()`
Note that `f.toURL()` is deprecated.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Relying on File will not work when the program is packaged as a .jar.

Comment: I managed to get the URL for the picture, but its still not appearing in the JPanel